# Missing PrintQueue from System.Printing

Tags: c#, system.printing, printqueue

I am coding C# in Visual Studio 2010. I want to add System.Printing.PrintQueue (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printqueue(v=vs.100).aspx) to my code, but the dropdown list doesn't seems to have it. How do I solve this? Screenshot: http://imgur.com/GAB6QcD

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have not added `system.printing` to your references.

Comment: it's added, i can't post a screenshot directly here yet as my reputation is not high enough. I made a screen shot and uploaded to imgur. It's in my first post.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a reference to ReachFramework